# How to revert an installed feature to be advertised?

Tags: windows-installer

I have a feature in my product that I would like to be installed on demand via assigned advertising (i.e., [it's installed for real when an advertised file, shortcut or COM class is accessed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367548(VS.85).aspx)).  There are some security implications associated with installing this feature, which is why I would like it to be only installed when it's required.  For the same reason, I would also like the feature to be removed when it is no longer needed.  Ideally, it would become advertised again, so that it could be re-activated if required.

Is it possible, using standard MSI technology, to revert a feature to the advertised state, rather than removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Installer API function "MsiConfigureFeature".
There you can control the state of the Feature.

[MSDN - MsiConfigureFeature Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370069(VS.85).aspx)