# MSI Install-on-demand best practices?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I'm working on a new feature for our product, a component of which has some fairly major security implications: it runs as a WCF service, and performs some highly-privileged actions.  As such, I'd like that component to only be installed when the user requires it (and removed when it's no longer required), and for the installation to be accomplished programmatically.

I've looked into [advertising](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367548(VS.85).aspx) (specifically, assigned installs), and it appears to be a good mechanism for accomplishing this.  [I'm not sure whether the installation of an advertised feature can be undone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721322/how-to-revert-an-installed-feature-to-be-advertised), however, which would be useful for removing the component when it's no longer required.  I'm also not completely sure whether programmatic installation could be achieved with advertising: [advertised COM classes seems to be discouraged](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/3/12/RobMens-Recommendation-Do-not-advertise-COM-information-in-MSI).

I'm wondering, therefore, if a simple call out to msiexec to install/remove the component would be more sensible.  The component could be packaged in a separate MSI, or as a separate feature of our main MSI.

What techniques have you used for installing features on demand?

Comment: The problem with advertising is the the MSI source needs to be always available. If your planning to using AD and publish the setup, its not a big problem, but if the setup comes from a CD then your in problem. Network share also tends to change. (cont...)

Comment: separated MSIs sound like a good idea, you can call MsiInstallProduct instead of executing msiexec.msi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by installing all the necessary bits and pieces up front and then starting/disabling the WCF Service as required.